# Is it possible in terrafom to define an object as variable for resource in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

my config.tf

```
 variable "tag_for_ec2" {

  description = "Tags for ec2"
   type        = any
 }

 

 resource "aws_instance" "terraform-ec2" {
 ami           = "ami-02f26adf094f51167"
 instance_type = "t2.micro"
 tags          = var.tag_for_ec2.Name
 }
```

above is the config syntax for deploying ec2 through terraform, i am trying to an **entire object for tags attribute.** i know tags in terraform docs is written like this

```
tags = {
     Name = "Created by Terraform"
   }
```

terraform.vars file

```
tag_for_ec2 = {
    Name = "created by jatin/terraform"
}
```

Upon running terraform apply it gives this error

```
Inappropriate value for attribute "tags": map of string required.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[tags](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/instance#tags) is a map, and your `var.tag_for_ec2` is already a map. So it should be:

```
resource "aws_instance" "terraform-ec2" {
   ami           = "ami-02f26adf094f51167"
   instance_type = "t2.micro"
   tags          = var.tag_for_ec2
 }
```

Comment: @JatinMehrotra No problem. Glad it worked:-)

Comment: @JatinMehrotra You can check https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214788/aws-chat Its a "meeting" place for SO AWS community.